# Adding a macro to an Excel spreadsheet with Java

Tags: java, excel

I'm developping an app that creates an Excel spreadsheet. I'm using Java with [docx4j](http://dev.plutext.org/trac/docx4j) library, but it does not have Macro support since it is not provided through Open XML API. I was just wondering if anyone knew of a workaround to add a macro to an existing Excel spreadsheet using Java (even with another library).

Thanks

Comment: I'm dubious you'll find anything java-based for this (but i could be wrong!). Presumably you can add macro's via native MS technologies (.NET, c# etc) Is this an option?

Comment: The main portion of the app must be coded using Java. But if it's possible (I'm far from being a Java expert), I can add a C# script doing this. Is it possible to launch a C# script from Java ?

Comment: you can launch any process from java. Don't think you can actually execute .NET/c# within the JVM though.

Comment: Yeah I figured the JVM couldn't execute C#/.NET code. I'll look into making a C# script to add the macro. Thanks ! (You should make an answer so I can accept it)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it's the same macro in all Workbooks you might be able to use a template? Meaning you have an empty workbook which contains the generalized makro and this will be copied for each "new" Workbook your need to create from Java.

Comment: Can you please explain how can we achieve this. I have a .xlsb file with macro and I want to update few cells of this file. Generated new excel should have same macro intact.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you'll find anything java-based that will be able to do this for you. However I guess native MS technologies (.NET, c# etc) will be able to do this. Although (AFAIK) you can't actually execute c# in the JVM, you can make system calls from java to execute another program using [Runtime.exec()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html).