# Insert a checkbox in an Excel sheet using Apache POI

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, poi-hssf

I want to pragmatically insert a number of checkbox in different cells. I want to keep a reference for each one in order to read them later on after the user check or uncheck.

Can I do that in Java POI ? if not what is other alternatives to do it?

thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can create custom check box with macros with help of **Microsoft visual basic+java** , in java alone that facility is not available

Comment: can you be a bit more specific? what should i do  to implement this?

Comment: excel is a product of Microsoft , whereas java is a product from oracle , so by java itself `you cannot add any change in Excel` , with help of **Microsoft VB** coding only you can do it,    [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5911285/adding-a-macro-to-an-excel-spreadsheet-with-java]